# How do I close an account, empty the rent into a wrapped sol account, and then sync it?

Tags: solana

I have an account that stores some data and is owned by my Solana program. I'd like to implement a `Close` instruction that "closes" the account and transfers the remaining native-SOL into a wrapped-SOL token account, and then call [spl-token's sync_native instruction](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L1288-L1299).

If I try to use the SystemProgram's `Transfer` instruction, I hit the error [in the processor](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/b44847203743130440f8f18af964ac590cefa82c/runtime/src/system_instruction_processor.rs#L176-L179) that says `Transfer: from must not carry data`.

So instead, I just do this:

```rust
let dest_starting_lamports = dest_account_info.lamports();
**dest_account_info.lamports.borrow_mut() = dest_starting_lamports
        .checked_add(source_account_info.lamports())
        .unwrap();

**source_account_info.lamports.borrow_mut() = 0;
```

However, if I later call `sync_native` via CPI anywhere in the same instruction, I get an error:

```
sum of account balances before and after instruction do not match
```

Is it possible to both modify the lamport values (transfer) of accounts AND call a CPI instruction? Or alternatively, is there a way to close the account with the SystemProgram?

Answer (score 2):

Okay So here I want to figure it out that CPI in a single instructions causes conflict with each other
as in my case I was using token program and system program in a single instruction
and I figured it out that token program CPI should be done above the system program CPI.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug in the runtime, because otherwise it looks like you're doing everything correctly.  The only time this should fail is if `dest_account_info` and `source_account_info` are the same, but you mentioned that the `sync_native` is what caused the problem.

As a workaround, you can have `sync_native` done as a separate instruction in the transaction rather than as a CPI.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Jon C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70794043/5057425), this seems to be the relevant runtime issue: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/9711

In short, it seems like you must not have any CPIs after directly manipulating accounts' lamports or this error will be thrown. So put that code block in the last part of your instruction processor and it should be good